# Attempt To Use Batch Files While Keep Structure

Tags: windows, batch, file-transfer, robocopy, xcopy

I wanted to use `robocopy`, but it is not possible due to my text file has filenames attached.
I ended up have to use `copy` instead.

I wanted to copy files like this...

```
Source: S:\folder\A\B\C\D\E\product_pdf\Drive\DriveDeluxeAluminumBathChair_RTL12202KDR.pdf
Destination: C:\wamp64\F\G\product_pdf\Drive\DriveDeluxeAluminumBathChair_RTL12202KDR.pdf
```

Here is how my text file (ActivePDF.txt) listed..

```
product_pdf\Drive\DriveDeluxeAluminumBathChair_RTL12202KDR.pdf
product_pdf\Drive\DriveCommodesNRS185007-11117N.pdf
product_pdf\Drive\DriveCommodes11125Series.pdf
product_pdf\Drive\DriveSuctionCupGrabBar_RTL13082.pdf
product_pdf\Drive\DriveChromeKnurledGrabBar.pdf
```

My attempted batch file is looked like this

```
@echo on
enableextensions 
set main_folder=S:\folder\A\B\C\D\E
set my_folder=C:\wamp64\F\G
set log_file="%main_folder%\CopyLog.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (ActivePDF.txt) do if exist "%main_folder%\%%a" (
    md "%my_folder%\%%a" 2>nul
    copy /v /y "%main_folder%\%%a" "%my_folder%\%%a"
)
```

It did copied, but it ended up created folder with ".pdf" and actual PDF files are inside that ".pdf" folders. (Therefore, each PDF contained in the own folder...)

I think I'm getting there... but I do wonder if there is any cleaner way to do it.

Comment: It's `md "%my_folder%\%%a" 2>nul` that's creating the subdirectories and causing your problem: omit this line and all your files will be copied to `%my_folder%`. To emphasise the point, you can omit `%%a` from the copy target, ie `copy /v /y "%main_folder%\%%a" "%my_folder%\"`.

Comment: If you need to make sure that the directory path exists in the target, replace the `md` line by `md "%my_folder%\%%a\.." 2>nul` (this is a trick to avoid parsing the `%%a` variable).

Comment: It ended up copy "my_folder" without sub directories that I'm intended to put into.
I do needed those PDF files into sub directories as stated in text files.

Comment: If you want the source directory structure recreated in `"%my_folder%"`, then you can use the same trick with the `md` on the `copy` command: `copy /v /y "%main_folder%\%%a" "%my_folder%\%%a\..\"`.

Comment: Yep, this copy command is the answer! `copy /v /y "%main_folder%\%%a" "%my_folder%\%%a\..\"`
So, all I truly need is the `\..` part to go up by one folder!

Comment: I've made my comments into an answer, so others can see that your problem has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the commands in the `for` loop that are causing the problem: `%%a` contains both the subdirectory path and the PDF file name, so `md "%my_folder%\%%a" 2>nul` will create in the target folder a directory path which includes the PDF name as the last subdirectory.

When the target path is a directory the `copy` command copies the source file(s) into it, with the result you observed.

While it is possible to parse `%%a` to extract the directory path and file names, there is a trick that can be used to reference the directory path without parsing: if `%%a` contains a file name with directory path, then `%%a\..` will reference the directory path. Even though `%%a` is a file path, the parsing of `%%a\..` will identify the containing directory without checking whether the last element of `%%a` is a file or directory.

So the commands in the `for` loop become:-

```
md "%my_folder%\%%a\.." 2>nul
copy /v /y "%main_folder%\%%a" "%my_folder%\%%a\.."
```

The `md` is needed to create the target subdirectory if it does not exist.